# SpriteKit - Collision detection not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

i've got a problem with the collisions.

adding physicbody depending on tilemap:

```
 guard let tilemap = childNode(withName: "LevelGround") as? SKTileMapNode else { return }

    let tileSize = tilemap.tileSize
    let halfWidth = CGFloat(tilemap.numberOfColumns) / 2.0 * tileSize.width
    let halfHeight = CGFloat(tilemap.numberOfRows) / 2.0 * tileSize.height
    for row in 0..<tilemap.numberOfRows {
        for col in 0..<tilemap.numberOfColumns {
            if tilemap.tileDefinition(atColumn: col, row: row) != nil {
                let x = CGFloat(col) * tileSize.width - halfWidth
                let y = CGFloat(row) * tileSize.height - halfHeight
                let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tileSize.width, height: tileSize.height)
                let tileNode = SKShapeNode(rect: rect)
                tileNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
                tileNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: tileSize, center: CGPoint(x: tileSize.width / 2.0, y: tileSize.height / 2.0))
                tileNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
                tileNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                tileNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics().player | Physics().bullet
                tileNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics().ground
                tileNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Physics().ground | Physics().player
                tileNode.physicsBody?.friction = 0.1
                tileNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
                tileNode.strokeColor = .white
                tileNode.name = "Ground"
                self.world.addChild(tileNode)
            }
        }
    }
```

Let the bullet spawn on tapping the action2 button:

```
            if self.ctrlAction2.contains(touch.location(in: cam)) {
            let bullet = SKShapeNode(ellipseOf: CGSize(width: 5, height: 4))
            bullet.fillColor = .orange
            bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: bullet.path!)
            bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics().bullet
            bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics().enemy | Physics().ground
            bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Physics().bullet | Physics().enemy | Physics().ground
            bullet.position.y = charakter.position.y + charakter.size.height / 7
            bullet.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
            bullet.name = "bullet"
            if facing == "right" {
                bullet.position.x = charakter.position.x + charakter.size.width / 1.9
                self.world.addChild(bullet)
                bullet.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 2000, y: 0, duration: 4))
            } else if facing == "left" {
                bullet.position.x = charakter.position.x - charakter.size.width / 1.9
                self.world.addChild(bullet)
                bullet.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: -2000, y: 0, duration: 4))
            }
        }
```

The bullet collides with enemies, the enemies collides with the player and the player collides with the ground - everything works, except the collision between bullet and ground.

Thank you for your help in advance

Pascal

Comment: Be more precise. Does contact detection doesnt work, or a collisions doesnt work? Also what are the values for Bullet and Ground categories? And keep in mind that moving bodies by actions may interfere with effects of physics simulation. The only case where you are completely safe to use physics engine in combination with SKaction (for changing node position) is if you only interested in contact detection.Otherwise, say in the case of collisions, you may end up with an unexpected behaviour because you are affecting on node's position in two ways at the same time.

Comment: Both don't work. The values for the Bullet and Ground categories are simply 2 & 3. Should i use bitshifting instead?

Comment: And also, aside from values of cateogry masks, I would check if bullet's physics body is not nil. Put a break point after you initialize bullet's body and see if it has body at all.

Comment: It's not possible that bullets physics body is nil, because the collision with the enemy is working correctly.

Comment: You should use power of 2. Eg 1,2,4,8,16, 32 for bit masks... not 1,2,3...

Comment: Changed it, but it's not working :(

Comment: Leave it like that, because that is a proper way to define masks. Now try to move a bullet using physics, by applying impulse to it.

Comment: When i'm trying to apply impulse, the bullets spawn at the expected location and stay there. They are not moving.

Comment: Using SKPhysicsBody(circleOf: xxx) instead of edgeLoop and everything is fine... :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you use applyImpulse() method? Try to force unwrap physics body, like this bulletnNde.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(...) and see if it crashes. It sounds like your bullet's physics body is nil.

Comment: Oh yeah... using edgeLoop makes a static physics body ... how did I miss that :)